# Exception raised when setting Trigger against ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am revisiting a MVVM Windows Phone project I have worked on and I am experiencing an issue when I am adding a Trigger to a ListBox. I have upgraded my project to 7.1. I previously had code as follows :-

```
            <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Margin="12"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListItemStyle1}"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 i:Interaction.Triggers="{StaticResource PerformSelectionChangedEventTrigger}" />
```

However I am now receiving an exception as follows :-

Cannot set read-only property 'System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.Triggers

Making the following change seems to solve the issue :-

```
            <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyListItems}"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Margin="12"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListItemStyle1}"
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentSelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                  
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmdextras:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=PerformSelectionChanged}"
                                              PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
```

I have searched for the exception message however I am unsure why the "inline" trigger setting use to work and no longer works.

Would someone be able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, when you do it *inline* you **set** the value. You're setting a collection.

It is often advised to make collections readonly, they probably changed that bit, and by doing it the other way, you **add** to the collection, which is no problem even if the collection is readonly.